# Ruby, multidimensional array push error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

```
  array = [[]]
  for level in 0..counter-1
    for line in 0..counter-1
      array[level].push(rectangle[x+level][y+line])
    end
  end
```

I get this error **NoMethodError: undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass**

I want to find all squares inside a rectangle, but when I try to save that square in to custom array I get an error.

```
array[level].push(rectangle[x+level][y+line])
```

all I want to do here to generate a square like for example array[[3, 4],[5, 2]] which would be

`3 4
 5 2`.
the problem is that `array[0].push(rectangle[x+level][y+line])` with number instead of variable is working, but with variable 'level' it gives me error, however if i use constant number i cannot generate multi level array.

any help?

Comment: Please show where `counter` and `rectangle` come from.

Comment: `rectangle` is function parameter (2d array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `array` only has one element, that's why it was working for level = 0. You can easily fix it like this:

```
 array = []
 for level in 0..counter-1
   array.push []
   for line in 0..counter-1
     array[level].push(rectangle[x+level][y+line])
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

found a solution

```
  2darray = [[]]
  i=0
  for level in 0..counter-1
    array = []
    for line in 0..counter-1
      array.push(rectangle[x+level][y+line])
    end
    2darray.push(array)
```

generate 1d array and append it to 2d  array

Comment: couple of issues with this. The first for loop is never closed, the final 2d array would have an empty array as its 1st element